# New review request from Perforce

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to send a pending change list for review in perforce. But I am getting the error

> Error: Unable to run rbt.exe

(see the screenshot). How can I fix that?

[image: P4V screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a trigger (or perhaps a custom tool?) that's trying to execute "rbt.exe" and it's failing.  Googling that executable name I'm guessing it's this: https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/dev/rbt/commands/post/

To fix it you might need to reinstall ReviewBoard, or otherwise fix whatever is wrong with it.